# Angularjs + typescript controller resolve troubles

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

This script

https://gist.github.com/whisher/6231714

give me this error

Error: Unknown provider: albumsProvider <- albums

```
this.app.config(($routeProvider:ng.RouteProvider) => { 
            $routeProvider.
                    when('/', {
                        templateUrl: './view.html', 
                        resolve: {
                            albums: function(Album) {
                               console.log(Album);
                                return Album.getResource().query();
                            }
                        },
                        controller: 'AlbumController',
                        })

           } ); 
class AlbumController {
    constructor (private $scope,private albums) {
        this.$scope.test = '20 whatsomething';
        this.$scope.albums = albums;
    }
}
```

the Album is in the scope
console.log(Album); so

I'm waiting to get albums

in my controller but I get

only the above error :(

I don't really know which way to turn

can you give me an hint ?

Thanks

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: ok, I've edited the question ^^

Comment: The error is saying that angular can't resolve your dependency albums. Do you have a service 'albums'? Can you also post that code?

Comment: @John Hi, the service is Album, the albums is the resolve scope for the view.Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer** Angular can only dependency inject things you register with it. Since you have

```
this.app.service ('Album',Album);
```

You can only request for `Album` and not `album`. So modify your constructor from:

```
constructor (private $scope,private albums) {
    this.$scope.test = '20 whatsomething';
    this.$scope.albums = albums;
}
```

to:

```
    // You can only get variables injected that you registered with angular: 
    constructor (private $scope,private Album) {
        this.$scope.test = '20 whatsomething';

        this.$scope.albums = Album.getResource(). /* Send your request based on http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource */
    }
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=declare%20var%20angular;%20%0A%20%0A%0Aclass%20MyApp%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20app;%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.app%20=%20angular.module%28%27myApp%27,%20%5B%27ngResource%27%5D%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.app.config%28%28%24routeProvider%29%20=%3E%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%09%24routeProvider.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20when%28%27/%27,%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20templateUrl%3a%20%27./view.html%27,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20albums%3a%20function%28Album%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28Album%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Album.getResource%28%29.query%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20controller%3a%20%27AlbumController%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.app.service%20%28%27Album%27,Album%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aclass%20AlbumController%20%7B%0A%09//%20You%20can%20only%20get%20variables%20injected%20that%20you%20regiestered%20with%20angular%3a%20%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%20%28private%20%24scope,private%20Album%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24scope.test%20=%20%2720%20whatsomething%27;%0A%09%09%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24scope.albums%20=%20Album.getResource%28%29.%20/%2a%20Send%20your%20request%20based%20on%20http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource%20%2a/%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Resource%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%20%28public%20%24resource%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20setResource%28params%3aIParams%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09this.%24resource%20=%20this.%24resource%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20params.path,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20params.params,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20params.methods%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20getResource%28%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09return%20this.%24resource;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Album%20extends%20Resource%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20params%3aIParams%20=%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3a%20%27./albums.json%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20params%3a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3a%20%27@id%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20collection%3a%20%27@collection%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20methods%3a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20query%3a%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20method%3a%20%27GET%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20isArray%3a%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor%20%28public%20%24resource%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%28%24resource%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setResource%28this.params%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%7D%0Ainterface%20IParams%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20path%3astring;%0A%20%20%20%20params?%3aany;%0A%20%20%20%20methods?%3aany;%0A%7D%0A%20%0Anew%20MyApp%28%29;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but if I add your snippet https://gist.github.com/whisher/6231714 I've got error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'albums'.

Comment: updated answer. Personal note, I much prefer $http over $resource : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Comment: I can see the point but I updated the gist https://gist.github.com/whisher/6231714 with a flat example and it still doesn't work but it's quite strange because I take as example like that from https://github.com/shyamseshadri/angularjs-book/tree/master/chapter4 and there it works I don't understand whats the problem

Comment: mmm I suppose it's a asynchronous issue because I updated the gist again with a trivial flat js example and it works https://gist.github.com/whisher/6231714